# Cómo puedo saber en que formato esta una fecha en python?

Tags: python, date, formato

Eso pues, tengo estas fechas: `date1="21/10/2021"` y `date2="21-Oct-2021"`

Y tengo esto (aunque no creo que funcione, obviamente ya importe todo lo de datetime):

```
date1.format()
date2.format()
```

La cosa es que quiero que me salga esto:

```
"%d/%m/%Y"
"%d-%b-%Y"
```

Respectivamente

¿Cuáles serían las soluciones posibles?

Comment: No es posible con la biblioteca estándar python. Quizás usando módulos de terceros como `dateparser` o `maya`, pero por lo que he podido ver en su documentación tampoco te ofrecen esa utilidad. Aunque sí que son capaces de convertir al formato `datetime` cualquier cadena que les pases,  y por tanto parece que son capaces de adivinar el formato en que están, no retornan esa información. Y por lo que he podido ver parece que lo que hacen es básicamente iterar por una gran lista de formatos posibles hasta dar con uno que funcione.

Answer (score 2):

Como dijo Abulafia, la biblioteca estándar no ofrece una forma de saber el formato de una fecha. Sin embargo, se puede usar las mágicas expresiones regulares para analizar la cadena y deducir el formato de ese modo.

#### Solución

Usando el modulo re y expresiones regulares, pude armar el siguiente código junto a una función que hace lo que pides:

```
import re

# si quieres agregar o modificar formatos, hazlo aqui
formatos = dict(formato1="[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}",
                formato2="[0-9]{2}-(ene|feb|mar|abr|may|jun|jul|ago|sep|oct|nov|dic)-[0-9]{4}")

formatos_re = re.compile("|".join("(?P<%s>%s)" % item for item in formatos.items()), flags=re.IGNORECASE)

# si quieres agregar o modificar formatos, hazlo aqui también.
group_to_format = dict(formato1="%d/%m/%Y", formato2="%d-%b-%Y")


def get_format(cadena):
    match = formatos_re.fullmatch(cadena)

    if(match is None):
        raise ValueError("Formato desconocido")
    else:
        return group_to_format[match.lastgroup]
```

Este código asume que la fecha está bien escrita.

#### Analisis de la solución

Vamos a analizarlo por partes:

```
import re
```

Importamos el modulo re, que nos permitirá trabajar con expresiones regulares.

```
formatos = dict(formato1="[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}",
                formato2="[0-9]{2}-(ene|feb|mar|abr|may|jun|jul|ago|sep|oct|nov|dic)-[0-9]{4}")
```

Esto crea un diccionario. La clave será un nombre cualquiera que le queramos dar al formato (solo puede tener letras, numeros y guion bajo) y el valor será una expresión regular que deberá coincidir con el formato esperado.
Este diccionario se usará luego para construir una sola expresión regular.

formato 1 coincide con dos numeros seguidos de una barra seguido de otros dos numeros seguido de una barra seguido de cuatro numeros. Ej: "12-12-2020", "99-99-9999"

formato 2 coincide con dos numeros seguidos de ene, feb, mar, abr, may, jun, jul, ago, sep, oct, nov o dic seguido de cuatro numeros. Ej:"12-ene-2020", "99-dic-2020"

Puedes ver y probar las regex [formato1](https://regexr.com/66nig) y [formato2](https://regexr.com/66nim) en estos links. También tienes una explicación de que es cada cosa allí (en ingles).

Sin embargo, dejaré una explicación general de lo usado por si los links se caen o no sabes nada de ingles.

- `[0-9]` Coincide con un numero del 0 al 9.
- `{n}` Dice que la expresión anterior se repite n veces. Por ejemplo [0-9]{2} se asegura de que la coincidencia [0-9] ocurra dos veces.
- `palabra` Esto es facil, coincide con esa misma palabra.
- `(expresion1|espresion2...|expresionn)` Esto coincide con la primera expresión o la segunda o ... la expresion n. | es como el or de Python. Por ejemplo (enero|febrero) coincidirá con enero o febrero.

  formatos_re = re.compile("|".join("(?P<%s>%s)" % item for item in formatos.items()), flags=re.IGNORECASE)

Esto genera la expresión regular, cada expresión regular del diccionario anterior se guarda en un grupo con nombre. Esto genera la siguiente expresión regular: `(?P<formato1>[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})|(?P<formato2>[0-9]{2}-(ene|feb|mar|abr|may|jun|jul|ago|sep|oct|nov|dic)-[0-9]{4})`. El flag re.IGNORECASE hace que de lo mismo que algo esté en mayusculas o minusculas, coincidirá igual. Por ejemplo, sep y SeP coincidirán con la expresión regular.
En la variable formatos_re se guarda el la expresión regular compilada.

```
group_to_format = dict(formato1="%d/%m/%Y", formato2="%d-%b-%Y")
```

Cuando recuperemos el formato coincidente, lo que obtendremos es formato1 o formato2, no lo que vos esperas. Esto tiene el propósito de convertir ese nombre en lo que deseas.

Ahora nos adentramos en la función:

```
match = formatos_re.fullmatch(cadena)
```

Usamos el método fullmatch para decir "esta cadena tiene que coincidir en su totalidad con la expresion regular que creamos más arriba". Esto devolverá un objeto match si hubo una coincidencia, si no devolverá None.

```
if(match is None):
    raise ValueError("Formato desconocido")
```

Si no se encontró ninguna coincidencia, es decir el valor de la variable match es None, generamos un error que dice que el formato es desconocido.

```
else:
    return group_to_format[match.lastgroup]
```

Si se encontró una coincidencia, entonces obtenemos el nombre del ultimo grupo coincidente y lo convertimos con el diccionario mencionado más arriba en la cadena que buscas obtener. Posteriormente lo retornamos.

#### Unas palabras más

Como habrás notado, el uso de expresiones regulares es muy útil. Yo creo que tanto para cualquier cosa que quieras hacer en el futuro como para expandir mi solución a otros formatos de fecha o modificarla, te convendría aprendertelas. Este modulo está muy bien documentado en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html).

Si no, cualquier cambio que quieras hacer dimelo y editaré la respuesta!